# How does test fail with both "TestsFailedException" and "Failed 0, Errors 0"

Tags: scala, sbt, akka, scalatest

Intermittently some ScalaTest test runs fail with this contradictory output:

```
...
akka.pattern.AskTimeoutException: Timed out
    at akka.pattern.PromiseActorRef$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(AskSupport.scala:334)
    at akka.actor.Scheduler$$anon$11.run(Scheduler.scala:118)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$InternalCallbackExecutor$.scala$concurrent$Future$InternalCallbackExecutor$$unbatchedExecute(Future.scala:694)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$InternalCallbackExecutor$.execute(Future.scala:691)
    at akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler$TaskHolder.executeTask(Scheduler.scala:455)
    at akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler$$anon$12.executeBucket$1(Scheduler.scala:407)
    at akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler$$anon$12.nextTick(Scheduler.scala:411)
    at akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler$$anon$12.run(Scheduler.scala:363)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
[error] Could not run test com.example.Spec: akka.pattern.AskTimeoutException: Timed out
...
[info] ScalaTest
[info] Run completed in 20 seconds, 772 milliseconds.
[info] Total number of tests run: 64
[info] Suites: completed 12, aborted 0
[info] Tests: succeeded 64, failed 0, canceled 0, ignored 0, pending 0
[info] All tests passed.
[error] Error: Total 64, Failed 0, Errors 0, Passed 64
[error] Error during tests:
[error]     com.example.Spec
[error] (price-finder/test:test) sbt.TestsFailedException: Tests unsuccessful
[error] Total time: 78 s, completed Jul 24, 2014 12:37:10 PM
```

How can I prevent these failures? If the test code is successful, I don't want the thrown exception to cause the test run to fail.

Comment: "Error during tests" is different from "Failed tests". It would help to see the relevant parts of the test case. Do you actually have 64 tests or 65 and one is not being run by the framework?

Comment: Your direction is right. The exception is in the Spec constructor. So while all tests in Spec are actually skipped, the test summary doesn't show them. I didn't catch the significance of "Error" in "Error during tests".

Comment: First of all, are you sure you are getting the exception from the thread of the test? Because if not, it will not trickle up to the test but to the top of the other thread (most probably a worker thread from an ExecutionContext or Dispatcher)

Answer (score 2):

ScalaTest itself does not distinguish between errors and failures. Sbt does, though, as do JUnit and specs2. Is it possible you have a test written for a different test framework in the mix? In particular, what does com.example.Spec look like?

Comment: There are no other test frameworks used. The answer to my question seems to be as I commented, that a test class failed to initialize completely. So test cases aren't loaded and seem to disappear, rather than showing up as in error.

Answer (score 0):

These some possibilities why your branch is having such issues:-

- It might have conflicts, resolve and re-run the tests
- Git rebase is in progress, complete rebase and re-run those tests
- Test dependencies are not meet in my case docker images are not up as I was running the test.